# How to forceUpdate sibling component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have created a component which have two child components **AddContactList** and **ViewContactLists**, Here I need to **forceUpdate** **ViewContactList** when new entry inserted from AddContactList component

This is **AddContactList** components script

```
<script>   

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          fields: {},
          errors: {},
          success: false,
          loaded: true,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        submit() {
          if (this.loaded) {
            this.loaded = false;
            this.success = false;
            this.errors = {};
            console.log('Loading..');
            axios.post('/submit', this.fields).then(response => {
              this.fields = {}; //Clear input fields.
              this.loaded = true;
              this.success = true;
              console.log('done..');  
              // --Here I need to update ViewContactList component            
            }).catch(error => {
              this.loaded = true;
              if (error.response.status === 422) {
                console.log(error.response.data.errors)
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
              }
            });
          }
        },
      },
    }
</script>
```

This is **ViewContactList** components script

```
<script>
    import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination'
    export default {
        name:"ContactList",
        components:{
            pagination
        },
        data(){
            return {
                ContactList:{
                    type:Object,
                    default:null
                }
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.list()            
        },
        methods:{
            async list(page=1){
                await axios.get(`/getContactLists?page=${page}`).then(({data})=>{
                    this.ContactList = data                    
                }).catch(({ response })=>{
                    console.error(response)
                })
            }
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by emitting an event on successful save to the parent and then from parent component you can invoke the contact list component method with the help of `ref`.

Live demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('childone', {
  props: ['childmsg', 'childOneRef'],
  template: `<p>{{ childmsg }} <button @click="$emit('savesuccess')">Add Contact</button></p>`
});

Vue.component('childtwo', {
  props: ['childmsg', 'childoneref'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>',
  methods: {
    getupdtedList() {
        console.log('Contact List call');
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    callViewContactListCompMethod() {
        this.$refs.contactListRef.getupdtedList();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <childone @savesuccess="callViewContactListCompMethod" childmsg="This is a child 1 message">
  </childone>
  <childtwo ref="contactListRef" childmsg="This is a child 2 message">
  </childtwo>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your parent component is ContactComponent

ContactComponent

|--AddContactList

|--ViewContactList

When you insert contact in add contact list emit the @addList event to the parent component.
Then pass the contact list as a props to ViewContactList.
when the props is changed, the ViewContactList component will be re-rendered automatically.